# Batch Renaming of Files in sub-directories based on a .xlsx

Tags: python

There is a directory in `C:\Users\abcd\video`

Inside the directory, there are a lot of `.mp4` files.

How do I rename all `.mp4` files based on an Excel sheet that contains following information using Python:

[image]

For example, the current filename is `A.mp4`. I would like to rename it to `1.mp4`.

Comment: So your question is about how to rename? or how to parse excel file to get the old and new names?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is about how to rename by parsing excel file to get the old and new names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**
If you want to use an Excel file, with the extension *.xlsx*
After installing xlrd, i.e. a dependency for reading .xlsx files using the follwing command from the command line:

```
pip install xlrd
```

**Code:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Read your renaming data
dst = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\abcd\\video\\map.xlsx', header=None)
# Create a dictionary for easier access
dictionary = dict(zip(list(dst[dst.columns[0]]), list(dst[dst.columns[1]])))

# Renaming if filename ends with .mp4
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\abcd\\video"):
    if (filename.endswith(".mp4")):
        dest = str(dictionary[filename[:-4]]) + ".mp4"
        src = "C:\\Users\\abcd\\video\\" + filename 
        dst = "C:\\Users\\abcd\\video\\" + dest
        os.rename(src, dest)
```

**Edit2:**

Can use python3.4+ Path/pathlib to iterate recursively throught any folder

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

root = "C:\\Users\\abcd\\video\\"

# Read your renaming data
dst = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\abcd\\video\\map.xlsx', header=None)
# Create a dictionary for easier access
dictionary = dict(zip(list(dst[dst.columns[0]]), list(dst[dst.columns[1]])))

# Recursively reading all .mp4 files
files = list(Path(root).glob('**/*.mp4'))


for filename in files:
src = str(filename)
if(src[:src.rindex('\\')]==root):
    dest = src[:src.rindex('\\')] + str(dictionary[str(filename)[str(filename).rindex('\\')+1:-4]]) + ".mp4"
else:
    dest = src[:src.rindex('\\')] + "\\" + str(dictionary[str(filename)[str(filename).rindex('\\')+1:-4]]) + ".mp4"
os.rename(src, dest)
```

Comment: Please note that the input file is an excel file, not a txt file.

Comment: Actually he mentioned in the title that the file will be of extension `.xlsx`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think the output file is `.mp4`, not `.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In C:\\Users\\abcd\\video, there are multiple folders. The .mp4 videos are in those multiple folders. Does the provided code work at this situation?

Comment: Do you mean to say that C:\\Users\\abcd\\video this location has multiple nested folders?
And if so, do you wish to rename them without changing their location? Or do you just want to rename them?

And, no the provided code will not work for this. It would only work for the videos directly inside the \\video folder.

Comment: Yes, C:\\Users\\abcd\\video this location has multiple nested folders. I just want to rename them without changing their location.

Comment: Check my updated answer in Edit2. Please accept answer if it solves your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the actual .mp4 does not be renamed. May I have your support?

Comment: Hello, please try again, as I had forgot to replace _.txt_ to _.mp4_ while pasting the code to the answer. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you. I added os.rename(src,dest) at the end and work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can use the following approach (string formatting for python 3.6+):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

def rename_files(parent_dir, files_extension, filenames_map):
    """
    Rename files with specified extension located in subfolders of parent directory
    :param parent dir: Path to subfolder's parent directory
    :param files_extension: Renaming file's extension
    :param filenames_map: Mapping from initial filenames to target filenames
    :return: None
    """
    files_template = os.path.join(parent_dir, f'**/*{files_extension}')
    files = glob.glob(pathname=files_template, recursive=True)
    for file_path in files:
        base_dir, filename_with_ext = os.path.split(file_path)
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename_with_ext)
        try:
            new_filename = filenames_map[filename]
        except KeyError:
            raise Exception(f"There's no {filename} key in filenames mapping")
        new_file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, f'{new_filename}{extension}')
        os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)


filenames_map_file_path = r'C:\Users\abcd\video\filenames_map.xlsx'
parent_files_dir_path = r'C:\Users\abcd\video'
extension = '.mp4'

filenames_map = pd.read_excel(io=filenames_map_file_path, header=None) \
                  .set_index(0)[1] \
                  .to_dict()

rename_files(parent_dir=parent_files_dir_path,
             files_extension=extension,
             filenames_map=filenames_map)
```